# How to turn off motors for selected arm joints on PR2?

Tags: ros, pr2-controller-manager, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to only turn off some of the arm motors. I basically want to mimic the effect of turning of the arm controllers for the PR2, except I still want to control the wrist flex and roll.

Is there a way to turn off all of the other motors but still control the wrist roll/flex?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227212/how-to-turn-off-motors-for-selected-arm-joints-on-pr2?/) by [velveteenrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6196/velveteenrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out a hack to do this, which is to set the desired joints for the controller on the parameter server and then unload and reload the controller.

> rosparam set r_arm_controller/joints "[r_wrist_flex_joint, r_wrist_roll_joint]"

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager stop r_arm_controller

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager unload r_arm_controller

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager load r_arm_controller

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager start r_arm_controller

---

Originally posted by [velveteenrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6196/velveteenrobot/) with karma: 136 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0